# UTC Timestamp Conversion to Datetime Returns Unexpected Dates

Tags: python, datetime, utc

I have a list of dictionary objects in Python, a sample of which looks like this

```
data = [{'utcDay': 15846, 'count': 956}, {'utcDay': 15847, 'count': 1408}, {'utcDay': 15848, 'count': 1664}, {'utcDay': 15849, 'count': 1858}, {'utcDay': 15850, 'count': 1972}, {'utcDay': 15851, 'count': 2071}, {'utcDay': 15852, 'count': 2179}, {'utcDay': 15853, 'count': 2281}, {'utcDay': 15854, 'count': 2389}, {'utcDay': 15855, 'count': 2457}, {'utcDay': 15856, 'count': 2503}, {'utcDay': 15857, 'count': 2537}, {'utcDay': 15858, 'count': 2611}, {'utcDay': 15859, 'count': 2668}, {'utcDay': 15860, 'count': 2711}, {'utcDay': 15861, 'count': 2764}, {'utcDay': 15862, 'count': 2857}, {'utcDay': 15863, 'count': 2950}, {'utcDay': 15864, 'count': 2998}]
```

I would like to convert the contents of all of the "utcDay" keys to a Datetime object.

When I execute the following two utc timestamp conversions

```
for x in data:
    print(datetime.fromtimestamp(x["utcDay"]))

for x in data:
   print(time.ctime(x["utcDay"]))
```

I get the same output which is

```
1970-01-01 15:24:06
1970-01-01 15:24:07
1970-01-01 15:24:08
1970-01-01 15:24:09
1970-01-01 15:24:10
1970-01-01 15:24:11
1970-01-01 15:24:12
1970-01-01 15:24:13
1970-01-01 15:24:14
1970-01-01 15:24:15
1970-01-01 15:24:16
1970-01-01 15:24:17
1970-01-01 15:24:18
1970-01-01 15:24:19
1970-01-01 15:24:20
1970-01-01 15:24:21
1970-01-01 15:24:22
1970-01-01 15:24:23
1970-01-01 15:24:24
1970-01-01 15:24:25
...
```

I'm unclear as to why every timestamp is coming out as being from the 1970s since the original data, which is plotted on the source website, ranges from c.May 2013 to today.

Even when I multiply these timestamps by units of 1,000 / 10,000 / 100,000 / 1,000,000 I do not get the expected results. For example, this is the output I get from multiplying by 1,000

```
1970-07-03 19:40:00
1970-07-03 19:56:40
1970-07-03 20:13:20
1970-07-03 20:30:00
1970-07-03 20:46:40
1970-07-03 21:03:20
1970-07-03 21:20:00
1970-07-03 21:36:40
1970-07-03 21:53:20
1970-07-03 22:10:00
1970-07-03 22:26:40
1970-07-03 22:43:20
1970-07-03 23:00:00
1970-07-03 23:16:40
1970-07-03 23:33:20
1970-07-03 23:50:00
1970-07-04 00:06:40
1970-07-04 00:23:20
1970-07-04 00:40:00
1970-07-04 00:56:40
1970-07-04 01:13:20
...
```

Thanks for looking at my question.

Comment: for the function `fromtimestamp(timestamp)`, 0 is equivalent to 1970-01-01H00:00:00, you can check the [documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html). So that's the reason why you are getting the dates in that range. Maybe if you knew the "first" date of the website, since you said it ranges from 2017, you could apply an offset to the calculation

Comment: Looking at the data, it seems that the data is being outputted correct. It's the Unix timestamp that you're using that is either incorrect (x['utcDay']) or has some missing digits. A Unix timestamp is the number of seconds between a particular date and Jan. 1, 1970 at UTC.